# VHDL efficient and correct memory assignment

Tags: memory, vhdl

I'm trying to generate a memory for on FPGA, but I'm having some questions related to how I should approach the stored data. 
When I'd like to update data, do I need to use a new_q1 signal or not? (like I tried to apply in my code (version 1 and 3)). 
I was told that I need a new q1 signal (I don't exactly know why) and that I always should have an 'else' statement to prevent 'don't cares'.

Version 1 is the version with a new q1 signal, however, there is no initial value for new_q1. Version 2 is the version I actually started with but I received a comment that this is not the correct approach for some reason I don't quite understand.

Version 3 is the version that is fully working like it was explained to me, however, in my opinion, it is way too much and the synthesizer is rejecting my new_q1 constructions.

What version should I go with and can somembody clarify that what I'm being told is correct or not and why?

Version 1:

```
entity memory is
   port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    selector : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    write : in std_logic;
    value : out std_logic
    );
end memory;


architecture behaviour of memory is
    signal q1, new_q1 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk, reset) is
        begin
        if( clk'event AND clk = '1') then
            if(reset = '1') then
                q1 <= (others => '0');
            else
                q1 <= new_q1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
    process(q1) is
        if(write = '1') then
            new_q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector)) <= '1';
        else
            new_q1 <= q1;
        end if;
    end process;
    value <= q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector));
end behaviour;
```

Version 2:

```
entity memory is
   port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    selector : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    write : in std_logic;
    value : out std_logic
    );
end memory;

architecture behaviour of memory is
    signal q1 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk, reset) is
        begin
        if( clk'event AND clk = '1') then
            if(reset = '1') then
                q1 <= (others => '0');
            else
                if(write = '1') then
                    q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector)) <= '1';
                else
                    ....
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    value <= q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector));
end behaviour;
```

Version 3:

```
entity memory is
   port(
    clk : in std_logic;
    reset : in std_logic;
    selector : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    write : in std_logic;
    value : out std_logic
    );
end memory;

architecture behaviour of memory is
    signal q1 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk, reset) is
        begin
        if( clk'event AND clk = '1') then
            if(reset = '1') then
                q1 <= (others => '0');
            else
                q1 <= new_q1;   

            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    process(q1, write) is
        if(write = '1') then
            if(unsigned(selector) < 63) then
                new_q1 <= q1(63 downto to_integer(unsigned(selector))) & '1' & q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector)) downto 0);
            else
                new_q1 <= '1' & q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector)) downto 0);
            end if;
        else
            new_q1 <= q1;
        end if;
    end process;

    value <= q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector));
end behaviour;
```

Comment: Can you describe the required functionality of `memory`?  It appears that `write` is only used to set a bit, not assign a value, so bits are only reset at `reset`, thus it may be some special kind of memory.  Anyway, it looks like something is made too complicated, and `new_q1` is probably not needed, but again, it depends on the required functionality.

Comment: @MortenZilmer yes I can, it is only used to update and read a single bit out of this chunck of 64. In the final there will be q1, q2, q3 and q4 and 4 selectors will be given as input so there can be 4 single bit values given as output corresponding to those q1 - q4.

Comment: All FPGA vendors support synthesis of memories. For the exact language constructs you should find the application note from the FPGA vendor. It will have VHDL and Verilog examples. Beware that standard memories do NOT have a reset! The contents is supposed to be X from the start just like a real memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some assumptions about operation, as noted in the port list, a design may look like below.  Implementation in a FPGA is likely to be made using flip-flops, and not internal memories, due to size and the special function, so the name `memory` may be misleading through.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity memory is
  port(
    clk      : in std_logic;
    reset    : in std_logic;  -- Synchronous, assumed to be applied initially
    selector : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
    write    : in std_logic;  -- Write set bit only, synchronous
    value    : out std_logic  -- Read value, asynchronous
    );
end memory;

architecture behaviour of memory is
  signal q1 : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);
begin

  -- Reset and write set, synchronous
  process (clk) is
  begin
    if (clk'event and clk = '1') then  -- Rising clock
      if (reset = '1') then  -- Reset, synchronous
        q1 <= (others => '0');  -- Clear all bits
      elsif (write = '1') then  -- Write to set for selector bit
        q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector))) <= '1';  -- Set single bit
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  -- Read, asynchronous
  value <= q1(to_integer(unsigned(selector)));  -- Read single bit

end behaviour;
```

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate on what and especially why you did the things you did? I'm trying to understand

Comment: And, you did not use an else statement... (only else if). I was taught that an else statement is needed to prevent don't cares.

Comment: I will add comments to the code.  There is nothing special with `else` that prevents don't cares, but the internal memory will be undefined until reset, so the assumption is that reset is applied initially.